# Sort search results in the content search webpart based on managed property title with search keyword

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, content-search-web-part

How can I sort search results in the content search web part based on the managed property title?

I have tried sorting in query rule but there it needs to be hardcode the keyword. But I need to sort the results based on the search keyword that matches the search results title.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by managed property 'title'?

Comment: You can find Managed properties in the Search schema of your search service. Either from site setting->Search schema OR Central admin->Manage service applications then select your search service and then search schema.

Comment: You can find Managed properties in the Search schema of your search service. Either from site setting->Search schema OR Central admin->Manage service applications then select your search service and then search schema.

Answer (score 0):

To sort by Title managed property, make sure the Title is sortable
Navigate to CA->Application Management->Manage service applications->search service application->search schema->choose Title managed property , make sure it is sortable:
[image]

Then you can edit content search web part->change query->Sorting-> sort by Title:
[image]